# how to pass bool value from table view cell class to table view class in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I am passing my bool value from table view cell to table view class using delegates but unable to pass can anyone help me how to pass using any another method or if not correct me what's wrong while passing in it and in this it returning nil value ?

here is the code for my table view class

```
 class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,checkoutDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,boolValidationDelegate {
 var radio: Bool?
 func boolvalidation(bool: Bool)
    {
        radio = bool
    }
 @IBAction func continueButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print(radio)
        if radio == false {
            let radiobutton = SCLAlertView()
            _ =  radiobutton.showError("Warning", subTitle: "Please select shipping method", closeButtonTitle: "OK")
        }
        else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let addtoCartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "payment") as! PaymentMethodViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addtoCartVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingmethodcell", for: indexPath) as! MethodTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
```

here is my table view cell class

```
protocol boolValidationDelegate{
    func boolvalidation(bool: Bool)
}

class MethodTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
 var radioSelection: Bool?
 var boolDelegate: boolValidationDelegate?
func paymentRadioAction(button : KGRadioButton) {
        _ = button.center
        let centralPoint = button.superview?.convert(button.center, to:self.shippingTableView)
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint!)
        if button.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            radioSelection = true
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
        self.boolDelegate?.boolvalidation(bool: radioSelection!)
        print(radioSelection)
    }
```

Comment: cell. boolDelegate = self In CheckoutViewController

Comment: After you set the `boolDelegate`, like the answers below suggest, you should note that you have a strong reference cycle. You really want to make your protocol a `class` protocol (e.g. `protocol boolValidationDelegate: class { ... }`), and then make your `boolDelegate` a `weak` property. (I'd also rename the protocol to start with uppercase letter (e.g. `BoolValidationDelegate`), just as a matter of following standard programming conventions.)

Comment: Post the code how you are setting delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: posted the code above as you asked @raki

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaS Where you have added this line `cell.boolDelegate = self` inside your tableview `cellForRowAt` method ?

Comment: seems like you are setting delegate wrongly, your custom delegate variable name is boolDelegate, but you are setting delegate as cell.delegate. You should set delegate as cell.boolDelegate = self

Comment: yes @AdityaSrivastava

Comment: u r correct bro I had wrongly posted the delegate  @raki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `cell.boolDelegate` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`
 to `self` in `CheckoutViewController`

```
cell.boolDelegate = self
```

Comment: FYI, it's [`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview).

Comment: I am having this code already in my cell for row at index path @Baig

Answer (score 2):

You need to set delegate class In `CheckoutViewController` of  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
cell. boolDelegate = self
```

Comment: FYI, it's [`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview).

Comment: I am having the code already what u mentioned in cell for row at

Comment: Check paymentRadioAction this function calling or not, you are not passing anything if button selected